# How do I remove the effect of an extension from Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Installed a dark theme extension. Applied it, but started hampering some website's look, so deleted it. But, the effects are still persists as my [Light mode is complete dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVcjj.png) and [dark mode is grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGmS.png).  How do I fix this?

Things I've already done: Deleted the Extension from the Browser so that effect will go away. Tried re-installing Edge, it didn't work. Went in the Extension directory of AppData, but it's showing an empty folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the flag **Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents** has been enabled. You can go to **edge://flags/** and search for this flag. Setting it to `Default` or `Disabled` should resolve this issue.